# How do I force my std::map to deallocate memory used?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector, dictionary

I'm using a std::map, and I can't seem to free the memory back to the OS. It looks like,

```
int main(){
  aMap m;

  while(keepGoing){
    while(fillUpMap){
       //populate m
    }
    doWhatIwantWithMap(m);
    m.clear();//doesnt free memory back to OS

    //flush some buffered values into map for next iteration
    flushIntoMap(m);
  }
}
```

Each (fillUpmap) allocates around 1gig, so I'm very much interested in getting this back to my system before it eats up all my memory.

Ive experienced the same with std::vector, but there I could force it to free by doing a swap with an empty std::vector. This doesn't work with map.

When I use valgrind it says that all memory is freed, so its not a problem with a leak, since everything is cleared up nicely after a run.

edit:

The flush has to appear after the clear.

Comment: Note that your OS probably allocates address space when you try to allocate memory, but only allocates real, physical RAM when you touch the memory. And if you no longer use that RAM but other programs need it, its contents will be swapped out to disk. As a result freeing memory actually frees RAM.

Answer (score 17):

`m.clear()` releases memory back to the heap, but it's common for heap implementations to not release that back to the OS (even when they can, issues such as fragmentation make it hard).

This is how the default allocator works, if you've specified your own allocator for the map, it might have its own cache.  However, even in that case, it should be cached in order to be reused immediately anyway.

Maps don't have a concept of capacity vs size the way vectors do.

Answer (score 3):

That behaviour is normal, the runtime library keeps that memory allocated by the map class avaiable to the process so that the next time it needs to allocate memory it does not have to go to the operating system.  It is an run time library optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the map on the heap (via new), deleting it will free up any memory it used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a custom allocator, or just use [Boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html) pool library.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a simple test when I put some data in a std::map and then call std::map::clear().

```
typedef std::map<int, unit_t,std::less<int>,  
     my_allocator<std::pair<const int, unit_t>, 4 > > contaner_t;
contaner_t keys;
keys[1] = 10;
keys[2] = 20;
keys[3] = 30;
keys.clear();
```

this is the result of printf inserted in my test:

```
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:      56     (allocated   :       56)
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:     112     (allocated   :       56)
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:     168     (allocated   :       56)
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:     112     (deallocated :       56),
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:      56     (deallocated :       56),
Allocator # 4, Memory consumption:       0     (deallocated :       56),
```

I think you probably should also check your allocator behavior but I think your default std::allocator in fact deallocates memory as you expect but that memory is not returned to the OS. By the way what OS do you use?

The question here is how you measure `can't seem to free the memory back to the OS.` and how can you be sure that `I could force it to free by doing a swap with an empty std::vector.` Are you really sure that allocated memory in fact goes back to OS?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are on Linux.

If you really need to minimize the memory footprint of your application, you can call [malloc_trim()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) after clearing the map. I would also recommend taking a glance at [mallopt()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) manpage - it has some hints as to why your code could keep memory instead of returning it to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.1.2 of The Linux Programming Interface explains clearly about memory deallocation:

```
In general, free() doesn’t lower the program break, but instead adds the block of
memory to a list of free blocks that are recycled by future calls to malloc(). This is
done for several reasons:
- The block of memory being freed is typically somewhere in the middle of the
heap, rather than at the end, so that lowering the program break is not possible.
- It minimizes the number of sbrk() calls that the program must perform. (As
noted in Section 3.1, system calls have a small but significant overhead.)
- In many cases, lowering the break would not help programs that allocate large
amounts of memory, since they typically tend to hold on to allocated memory
or repeatedly release and reallocate memory, rather than release it all and then
continue to run for an extended period of time.
```