# How to release unordered_map memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

### Problem

I've seen that using `map.clear()` and `map.rehash(0)` doesn't release the expected memory from my RAM.

I created a program with the following code:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m1;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m2;
    
    // fill the maps m1 and m2 with 5 million elements

    // bucket_count = 5098259; size = 5000000
    
    // now I clear m1
    m1.clear();
    m1.rehash(0);
      // m1: bucket_count = 2; size = 0
      // m2: bucket_count = 5098259; size = 5000000

    // now I clear m2
    m2.clear();
    m2.rehash(1);
      // m1: bucket_count = 2; size = 0
      // m2: bucket_count = 2; size = 0
}
```

According to the `bucket_count` and `size` after each step of the program, it seems that there is a lot of space being released from RAM. However, checking the RAM used with a system monitor, I get the following evolution[image: ram evolution]

### Question

Even after clearing and rehashing both maps, the memory is only released when the program is finished. Actually there is a very little release of memory but I'm not sure if that's even possible to see in the picture. How is it possible?

How can I actually free that memory from the RAM?

### Context

I am using a Dynamic Programming algorithm to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem with 4Gb RAM in Linux. It crashes due to lack of memory, so I am trying to optimize the memory used by the program.

After some improvements I'm keeping two `unordered_map`:

- **costs**: stores the values of the previous iteration
- **new_costs**: is built during that iteration.

After an iteration ends, I swap them so **costs** has the new computed values, and I clear **new_costs** *trying* to free memory and start building the next iteration.

The code is something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> costs(5098259);
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> new_costs(5098259);

for (int m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
  new_costs.clear();
  new_costs.rehash(5098259);

  while (something) {
    // I build the content of new_costs based on the content of costs
  }

  std::swap(costs, new_costs);
}
```

At most I will have to store 2496144 and 2704156 elements in them respectively. That makes a total of **5200300** elements stored at the same time. Given that the key is a string with at most 70 chars --71 bytes-- and the value stored is a float --4 bytes--, I will have stored roughly 380 Mb.

I know that `unordered_map` is not memory efficient, but the program uses my RAM and my swap memory completely, so I must be missing something.

#### **EDIT for possible duplicate

**[How do I force my std::map to deallocate memory used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629018/how-do-i-force-my-stdmap-to-deallocate-memory-used)**

I've been using C++ for a week or so, and I don't know whether the memory management of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are the same, or if there are relevant differences between them.

I also don't know if *deallocate* means exactly the same as releasing the memory used by an object, so there is more RAM available.

In case both are the same, I am basically asking the same question. However, in any case, the answers to that question are explaining the reason behind the memory retention, rather than providing solutions to it.

Comment: Have you tried swapping it with an empty container?

Comment: The runtime might keep the memory for possible later reuse, and not return it to the operating system. Especially if you allocate many small units of memory.

Comment: Indeed, actually I'm very happy that by design it keeps its memory and that for some containers reserve is implemented that does exactly this. Memory allocation/deallocation is just way too slow in many cases. As said, just use a std::swap here and your memory should be really freed.

Comment: I'm astonished this isn't a duplicate, but I can't find a good match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force my std::map to deallocate memory used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629018/how-do-i-force-my-stdmap-to-deallocate-memory-used)

Comment: It's a match, but it's pretty old and the answers are ... just OK for me.

Comment: You are on a wrong track. You only should worry about freeing memory that you yourself allocate (look for `new` and friends in your code). If your container grows indefinitely, it's not because you fail to free its memory, it's because you insert more elements in it than you remove.

Comment: You may find it useful to learn the profiling tools available on your platform. If on Linux or BSD look into `valgrind`, it has a sub-tool called `massif` that will help you profile memory usage.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not using any `new` so far. The problem is that as memory keeps growing I reach the limit of RAM+swap and the execution gets killed. And I am sure that I will not use some data calculated in previous iterations, so why keep it?

Comment: @ZanLynx I've been reading part of the docs of valgrind. I understood that this will show when I leave blocks of code in memory inaccessible. But I think (I can definitely be wrong) this can happen if I use pointers, but I'm not using them. I just want to clear the `unordered_map` from RAM completely, and start filling it from 0 again.

Comment: You absolutely should not try to manage memory of the containers you have `clear()`ed. The standard library writers do it better than you, guaranteed. *memory keeps growing I reach the limit of RAM+swap and the execution gets killed* means that you keep adding elements to your containers **without** `clear()`ing or otherwise removing them. A container that is periodically `clear()`ed and only have a bounded number of elements in it at any given time will **NOT** cause indefinite growth of memory.

Comment: Your graph shows that you have bounded memory consumption. Your comment claims you have indefinite growth of memory that leads to a killed execution. The two claims cannot be true at the same time. Please decide which one is correct. If the graph is correct, you are doing everything right and have nothing to worry about. If the comment is correct, you are doing something wrong. We cannot know what exactly, but it is most probably not what you think. Post your entire program so that we can identify and discuss that unknown wrong thing.

Answer (score 5):

You have three levels of memory use to worry about, and your process memory footprint is probably showing you the wrong one.

1. **in-use memory**

   Stuff in use in your container. Easy.
2. **per-container allocator**

   Your container has an allocator. This may decide to allocate bigger chunks than requested, and may also keep released memory around for later re-use. Both of these generally improve speed at the cost of memory use.

   You can probably release this cache using the **swap trick**: create an empty temporary container and `std::swap` them. This moves the allocator as well, meaning any old cached storage will be released when the temporary goes out of scope.

   For some value of released, anyway: the memory will likely be returned to your ...
3. **process-wide dynamic allocator** (often "heap").

   This may decide to keep the memory cached in your process for exactly the same reason. It's under no obligation to return that memory to the system (until your process exits).

The only way to *force* your program to return memory to the system is to write your own allocator, using appropriate system calls to do this explicitly.

The sensible way to reason about your program's memory use, on a system with virtual memory, is to worry about how much memory is *used* and not worry too much about the size of its virtual address space.

NB. If memory use *keeps growing* despite you clearing and re-using containers, you either have a leak or are suffering from memory fragmentation. This really is a problem. When memory use just *doesn't decrease* during running, it's entirely normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think for now I will avoid writing my own allocator as this sounds a bit complex for my level of C++. The problem with my memory usage is that I reach the 4GB of RAM quite easily, and then using swap memory slows everything down. If I'm not going to use this data, why keep it? couldn't I use `new` and `delete` here? how would it be?

Comment: I agree that writing your own system-level allocator probably isn't the way to go in this case. However, your graph suggests memory is being re-used fine: to confirm, build `m1`&`m2`, clear them both, and _then do it again_. If the memory usage does _not_ increase the second time around, _nothing is wrong_. You may want to find some way to reduce memory use, but nothing is being leaked.

Answer (score 0):

What we do to release memory from stl containers like yours, is to swap them with an empty one. You can use this template for that:

```
template<typename T>
inline void freeContainer(T& p_container)
{
    T empty;
    using std::swap;
    swap(p_container, empty);
}
```

Instead of calling:

```
new_costs.clear();
```

You'd call

```
freeContainer(new_costs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I've copy-pasted it and the result of RAM used when using `clear()` and `rehash()` is equivalent to using `freeContainer()`. I have tried with `new` and `delete` but I don't manage to compile my program. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: How do you measure the RAM usage?